# List node directory throws SQL1027N

Tags: db2

I'm total noob for db2 and i started to learning it in our dev environment.

When I'm connected directly to a server and I execute *list node directory* command i get an message : SQL1027N  The node directory cannot be found.

Why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can mean that the Db2-server does not yet have any nodes defined.

In other words, when no nodes are defined the node-directory has not yet been created.

A Db2-server with local databases does not need to have any nodes defined, so it's not an error.

As soon as someone catalogs a node, the node-directory will get created, and an entry will be added, and the `list node directory` will then report what nodes are created.

Example:

`db2 list node directory`

```
SQL1027N  The node directory cannot be found
```

`db2 catalog tcpip node i9 remote myserver.whatever  server 60000`

```
DB20000I  The CATALOG TCPIP NODE command completed successfully.
DB21056W  Directory changes may not be effective until the directory cache is 
refreshed.
```

`db2 terminate`

`db2 list node directory`

```
 Node Directory

 Number of entries in the directory = 1

Node 1 entry:

 Node name                      = I9
 Comment                        =
 Directory entry type           = LOCAL
 Protocol                       = TCPIP
 Hostname                       = myserver.whatever
 Service name                   = 60000
```

`db2 catalog mydb at node i9`

```
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sourcing the db2profile in case your  shell environment has not been setup in your session

```
. sqllib/db2profile
```

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.gs.doc/doc/c0006321.html